# Passing variable to codebehind when using dynamic hyperlink with onserverclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im displaying a table of rows and want to have a delete button next to each row. The table is generated using a loop. Each link contains `onserverclick="deleteScheduleField"`. What i need to be able to do is `onserverclick="deleteScheduleField(rowid)"`, but this cant be done.

Most guides i have seen say to use the ID field, but since these rows are dynamically i cant do this. Whenever i try to use a dynamic Id i get the following error. If i add the following to the href i get the error `id="<%= scheduleField["id"] %>"`

> Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

I tried to look up a solution to this and people say to use `<%# %>` instead of `<%= %>`. I tried to do this and get the following error.

```
 <a runat="server" href="#" onserverclick="deleteScheduleField" class="<%# scheduleField["id"] %>">
```

> The server tag is not well formed.

To test my code behind works i created the following function and this works perfectly if i enter a non dynamic id.

```
public void deleteScheduleField(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlAnchor link = (HtmlAnchor)sender;
    Response.Write("DELETED " + link.ID );
}
```

How can i call this method and pass it a dynamic value?

Comment: Can you post the code that gave you "not well formed" error? I am pretty sure it can be easily corrected, as long as you are doing this using some repeater or other data bound control

Comment: I have updated the post with the line of code that gives me the not well formed error.

Answer (score 0):

the server tag is not well formed because of your quotes:

```
 "<%# scheduleField["id"] %>"
```

should be something like:

```
 "<%# scheduleField['id'] %>"
```

or

```
 "<%# scheduleField[" + id + "] %>"
```

Comment: error changes to CS1012: Too many characters in character literal when i change it to single quotes. scheduleField is a Dictionary object. When i change the html to class='<%# scheduleField["id"] %>' it tells me scheduleField doesnt exist in the current context. I know it does though as i can output values from it on the line above

Comment: What if you try '<%= #scheduleField["id"] %>' ? I may need to see more of the code to help further.

Comment: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.